# Suspected memory leak in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, iis, memory-leaks

I have a few asp.net applications running on my IIS6 server. And after I published a new one, it froze after a few hours. When i restart the app-pool it works again.

I see after I restart the app-pool that the memory footprint of w3wp.exe increases steadily by about 4-500kb each second, and it doesn't seem to stop.

How can I find out what is causing the memory leak?

Comment: I disabled Glimpse and it stopped. Hmm...

Comment: I found this article http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Memory_Leak_Detection.aspx

Comment: @ChristianWattengård Today, I debugged a memory leak as well and couldn't figure it out, and turns out it was Glimpse as well. Thanks for mentioning this.

Answer (score 1):

[Tess's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/) is the place for learning how to track these down.

[.NET Debugging Demos](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/02/04/net-debugging-demos-information-and-setup-instructions.aspx)